# Silverlight: Why do I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"?

Tags: silverlight

Sometimes I create a Silverlight project and I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" when I try and run it.  If I keep pressing refresh (usually 2 or 3 times) the page loads ok.  Occasionally, I also get the message dialog:

Webpage Error

Line: 56
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104
Category: InitializeError
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings

Other Silverlight projects still work fine.  Anyone know what causes this problem with some projects ?

Comment: Maybe this is some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548709/when-running-asp-net-project-i-get-internet-explorer-cannot-display-the-webpage

Comment: What version of IE are you seeing this in?

Comment: IE9 Beta (extra chars to make up comment)

Comment: I also sometimes get blank pages when running Silverlight apps. It seems entirely random: 95% of the time it works, about 5% it doesn't. Dunno why.  Annoying, but not so annoying that I've taken the time to determine what's up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me:

[Debugging Silverlight applications with IE9 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723247/debugging-silverlight-applications-with-ie9-beta/3749345#3749345)